# Ubuntu port is open but unable to telnet locally/remotely

Tags: networking, 22.04, ufw, telnet

I have tried to go through lots of documents/blogs but couldn't resolve my issue.

I have a local Ubuntu 22.04 installed inside vmware workstation with the IP address **192.168.100.108**. The server is running fine.

I have installed .net 6 on this server and my API project.
All went smooth till here and my api is able to execute locally you can see in the below logs.

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/kshahzad/repayment-api/ info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/pingrequest application/json - info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/pingrequest application/json - - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 201.3972ms info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/pingrequest application/json - info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/pingrequest application/json - - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 4.1817ms info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/pingrequest application/json - info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/pingrequest application/json - - 200 - application/json;+charset=utf-8 1.4804ms
```

If you see the above logs the API address is http://localhost:5000. From my host machine when I try to access the API I am not able to reach. So I tried to open the port in guest ubuntu server and here is the ufw status below screenshot is FYR.

```
kshahzad@netcore:~$ sudo ufw allow from any to 192.168.100.108 port 5000 proto tcp
Rule added
kshahzad@netcore:~$ sudo ufw status numbered
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 2] 5432/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 3] 27017                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 4] 192.168.100.108 5000/tcp   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
[ 5] 22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 6] 5432/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
[ 7] 27017 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

After opening the port, when I am trying to telnet I am unable to telnet.

```
kshahzad@netcore:~$ telnet 192.168.100.108 5000
Trying 192.168.100.108...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

When I telnet using the word localhost from the same ubuntu machine I am able to telnet successfully

```
kshahzad@netcore:~$ telnet localhost 5000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

*Just a side note from my Host Windows 11 machine I am able to telnet this ubuntu server on port 22.*

Can someone please guide what I am doing wrong or how can I address this.

Thanks